# Where to put PhoneGap project source?

Tags: cordova

I've worked with JqueryMobile to build HTML5 mobile apps. I use a cache manifest to serve the app when it's offline, but I still keep the files on the web server.

Last week, I setup a phonegap project. I noticed that PhoneGap wanted me to put the source files (html/js) in my native app wrapper so that they're on the device (Android), and have my activity look for the source there, instead of on my web server. I put the reference to the files back at the web for development purposes, but I'm wondering what is the best way to deploy to production.

**Is this just a matter of "ease of update" vs. a little latency?**

Doesn't the cache serve these files on subsequent request which only incurs a tiny bit of overhead (to check cache)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other factors in addition to "ease of update" vs. a little latency

- Enabling your app to run with or without an internet connection (when resources not cached)
- Dynamically loading app logic may lead to approval issues with the iPhone App Store